# В чем разница между понятиями MinGW, CygWin, GNU, GCC?

Tags: c++, c

Объясните разницу между понятиями `MinGW`, `CygWin`, `GNU`, `GCC` и какие между ними связи?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[GNU](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU) -- рекурсивный акроним от англ. GNU’s Not UNIX — «GNU не UNIX») — свободная Unix-подобная операционная система, разрабатываемая Проектом GNU.

[GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) -- Gnu Compiler Collection набор компиляторов с языков  C, C++, Objective-C, Fortran, Java, Ada и Go, а также библиотек для этих языков (libstdc++, libgcj,...).

[Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) --  Linux-подобное окружение (environment) для ОС Windows, которое позволяет переносить в нее программы выполняющиеся в [POSIX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) операционных системах (таких как Linux, BSD и Unix).

[MinGW](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) -- "минималистичная" GNU для Windows, перенос   GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) вместе с набором свободно распространяемых библиотек импорта, отладчика GDB, [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) и заголовочных файлов для Windows API.

[MSYS](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys) -- распространяемый вместе с MinGW набор утилит, таких как bash, gawk, grep и т.п., позволяющий строить приложения, которые зависят от традиционной среды UNIX.

Answer (score 2):

[**GNU**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Project) - это просто [набор](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GNU_packages) опенсорсных программ, авторы которых объединились по идеологическим причинам (создать и поддерживать полностью опенсурсные и со свободной лицензией операционные системы).

Для пользователя это в целом ничего не значит. Просто иногда в названии программ можно услышать приставку "GNU": GNU Make, GNU Compiler Collection, и т.п.

**GCC** - это GNU Compiler Collection (набор компиляторов для C, C++ и других языков). Но также так называется программа `gcc` (компилятор C из этого набора).

[**MinGW**](https://www.mingw-w64.org/) - в обиходе так называют GCC для Windows (т.е. он создает приложения для винды, но саму компиляцию можно выполнять на любой ОС). Но, строго говоря, это набор библиотек и инструментов, которые используют вместе с GCC (или другими компиляторами) для этих целей.

Есть два вида MinGW: оригинальный MinGW и **MinGW-w64**: второе - это форк первого. Сейчас почти все используют второй, хотя первый тоже жив в каком-то виде. В первом недостает важных фичей, например многопоточности (хедера `<thread>`).

У MinGW-w64 нет официального установщика, есть много неофициальных сборок разного качества.

[**Cygwin**](https://www.cygwin.com/) - это другой способ компилировать GCC под Windows. Он всячески притворяется линуксом (программа будет видеть все пути в линукс-стиле; какими-то костылями поддержаны `fork()` и прочие линуксовые вызовы, и т.п.).

Cygwin удобен для переноса существующих чисто линуксовых (`bash`, `grep`, `sed`, ...) утилит под Windows, если они не были изначально написаны кросс-платформенно. Новые программы писать под Cygwin сомнительно, лучше сделать нормальную кросс-платформенность.

[**MSYS2**](https://www.msys2.org/) - они распростряняют сборки свежего MinGW-w64 для Windows, плюс популярные библиотеки скомпилированные для него, и прочие полезности - в виде пакетов (они портировали для себя пакетный менеджер `pacman` с Арча).

Также они распростряняют некоторые утилиты, портированные с линукса с помощью своего форка Cygwin - `bash` и прочее, чтобы можно было запускать линуксовые скрипты (и мейкфайлы, и прочее) на винде.

Есть еще старый **MSYS** (MSYS1), который входит в комплект с MinGW (не -w64), и выполняет там похожие функции - в каком-то виде имитирует bash, и т.п.